# Asus H97-Plust and M.2 970/980 Compatibility

Tags: ssd, m.2

I plan on upgrading the SSD in my PC and after a few days of research, can't figure out if they are compatible.

My mainboard is Asus H97-Plus with m.2 (socket 3), M Key type 2242/2260/2280 up to 10 Gb/s.

I'm debating between the Samsung m.2 980 Pro and the 970 Plus. According to the crucial.com system advisor, this board supports PCIe NVMe Gen 4, which, as I understand, is compatible with the 980 Pro.
Am I right?

Comment: That it supports it - because retro-compatibility - doesn't mean you should do it. It seems a waste of a good and current NVMe drive on such old motherboard.

Comment: Avoid using SATA6G_5 and SATA6G_6 if you are going to use the M.2_3 connector. The manual for your motherboard holds all the answers to any question you possibly could want to know about your motherboard. **However, I'm afraid I have to disagree that a Samsung 980 Pro will work with that motherboard since it does NOT support NVMe devices.**

Comment: @Ramhound Google disagrees. There's even this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NGbbW6TqOvc And, as the author mentions, Crucial offers this: https://www.crucial.com/compatible-upgrade-for/asus/h97-plus Still, IMO a waste of a fine drive on old hardware.

Comment: I suppose it's at best PCIe 2.0 x4 (since the lanes are most likely offered by the PCH instead of the CPU). So unless there are other consideration (like durability or overall quality; or that the drive will soon be used on a much better platform), there's no point in spending extra money for a better (e.g. PCIe 4.0 or later) drive.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments.

Comment: @Ramhound, I know the bandwidth share with SATA6G_5 and SATA6G_6.